# Checkbox no sobrevive a los cambios de girar pantalla

Tags: java, android, livedata, viewmodel

Tengo una aplicación que estoy haciendo con la finalidad de practicar MVVM. Esta aplicación lo que hace es simplemente una llamada a Retrofit y pinta los datos de un JSON en un RecyclerView. En el row del RecyclerView tengo un checkbox cuya funcionalidad es que si está marcado, al pulsar un botón con u me muestra esos elementos marcados en otro RecyclerView de otro fragment. El problema es que cuando marco un check, antes de enviarlo ni nada, si yo giro la pantalla, es como que me vuelve a cargar la lista o no se muy bien que comportamiento está haciendo pero el caso es que ese checkbox vuelve a estar desmarcado y quiero que aunque yo no haya enviado esos cambios aún a Retrofit, esa pulsación del checkbox se mantenga:

Esta es mi clase para la vista:

```
package com.example.menunavegacion.ui.fragments.tabs.fragmentpets.view;

....

public class FragmentPets extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.recyclerView)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @BindView(R.id.progressBar)
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    PetsViewModel mWordViewModel;
    PetsAdapter adapter;

    @Inject
    RequestInterface requestInterface;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_one, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
        initViews();
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mWordViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PetsViewModel.class);

        mWordViewModel.getAllPets().observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<PetsDTO>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ArrayList<PetsDTO> petsDTOS) {
                adapter = new PetsAdapter(petsDTOS, getContext(), false);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

        mWordViewModel.getLoadingLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Boolean loading) {
                if (loading) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        mWordViewModel.loadJSON();

        mWordViewModel.showFinishMessage().observe(this, new Observer<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Boolean aBoolean) {
                if (aBoolean) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getActivity().getString(R.string.update_toast_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getActivity().getString(R.string.message_send_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btnSend)
    public void onSend() {
        mWordViewModel.updateList(adapter.getPetList());
    }

    private void initViews() {
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }
}
```

Este es mi ViewModel:

```
package com.example.menunavegacion.ui.fragments.tabs.fragmentpets.viewmodel;

....

public class PetsViewModel extends AndroidViewModel implements ViewModelInterface.ViewModel {

    private PetsRepository mPetsRepository;
    private LiveData<ArrayList<PetsDTO>> mAllPets;

    public PetsViewModel (Application application){
        super(application);
        mPetsRepository = new PetsRepository(application);
        mAllPets = mPetsRepository.getAllPetsLiveData();
    }

    public LiveData<ArrayList<PetsDTO>> getAllPets() {
        return mPetsRepository.getAllPetsLiveData();
    }

    public LiveData<Boolean> getLoadingLiveData() {
        return mPetsRepository.getLoadingLiveData();
    }

    public LiveData<Boolean> showFinishMessage() {
        return mPetsRepository.getFinishMessage();
    }


    @Override
    public void loadJSON() {
        mPetsRepository.useCaseLoadJSON();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateList(ArrayList<PetsDTO> pets) {
        mPetsRepository.useCaseUpdateList(pets);
    }
}
```

Este es el repositorio:

```
package com.example.menunavegacion.ui.fragments.tabs;

....

public class PetsRepository {

    LoadJSONUseCase loadJSONUseCase;
    UpdateListUseCase updateListUseCase;

    private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<PetsDTO>> allPetsLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<Boolean> loadingLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<Boolean> showFinishMessage = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public LiveData<ArrayList<PetsDTO>> getAllPetsLiveData() {
        return allPetsLiveData;
    }
    public LiveData<Boolean> getLoadingLiveData() {
        return loadingLiveData;
    }
    public LiveData<Boolean> getFinishMessage() {
        return showFinishMessage;
    }

    public PetsRepository(Application application) {
        loadJSONUseCase = new LoadJSONUseCase();
        updateListUseCase = new UpdateListUseCase();
    }

    public void useCaseLoadJSON() {
        loadJSONUseCase.loadJSON(new RepositoryInterface() {
            @Override
            public void showError(Boolean show) {
                showFinishMessage.postValue(show);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoading(boolean loading) {
                loadingLiveData.postValue(loading);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ArrayList<PetsDTO> data) {
                allPetsLiveData.postValue(data);
            }
        });
    }

    public void useCaseUpdateList(ArrayList<PetsDTO> pets) {
        updateListUseCase.updateList(pets, new RepositoryInterface() {
            @Override
            public void showError(Boolean show) {
                showFinishMessage.postValue(show);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoading(boolean loading) {
                loadingLiveData.postValue(loading);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ArrayList<PetsDTO> data) {
                allPetsLiveData.postValue(pets);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Este es mi usecase que se encarga de cargar el JSON de Retrofit:

```
package com.example.menunavegacion.ui.fragments.usecase;

....

public class LoadJSONUseCase {

    @Inject
    RequestInterface requestInterface;

    public LoadJSONUseCase(){
        DaggerComponenTest.builder().build().inject(this);
    }

    public void loadJSON(RepositoryInterface repositoryInterface) {
        Call<JSONResponse> call = requestInterface.getJSON();
        repositoryInterface.onLoading(true);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {
                repositoryInterface.onLoading(false);
                JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
                ArrayList<PetsDTO> data = new ArrayList<>();
                data.clear();
                data.addAll(jsonResponse.getPetsDTO());
                repositoryInterface.onSuccess(data);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
               repositoryInterface.onLoading(false);
               repositoryInterface.showError(false);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Este sería todo mi código. También acepto consejos sobre MVVM ya que estoy aprendiendo y bueno, son bienvenidos, asi que quedo en vuestras. Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Nadie que pueda darme alguna respuesta?

Comment: te sirvió la respuesta de Tyron Fonseca ?, si es así puedes votar o marcarla como solución, revisa [answer], saludos.

Comment: Si perdona, que he estado estos días bastante liado y no he podido ni entrar por aquí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar guardar tu arreglo en el bundle y recuperarlo despues de girar la pantalla.

Primero necesitas que tu modelo PetsDTO implemente Parcelable e implementa los metodos necesarios:

```
public class PetsDTO implements Parcelable {
...
}
```

Después en tu fragment utiliza los metodos de onSaveInstanceState para guardar el estado actual de tu lista en el Bundle:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("list", petsDTOS);
}
```

En tu inViewCreated() recupera el arrayList guardado en el Bundle:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null){
    //Recupera la lista del Bundle
    petsDTOS = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("list");
}else{
    //llena tu lista
}
```

Y en tu Activiy tambien necesitas guardar el estado del fragment utilizando los metodos de OnCreate y onSaveInstanceState:

```
Fragment fragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    if (savedInstanceState != null ) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "fragment");
    }else {
       fragment = new FragmentPets();
       getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmen_layout, fragment).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "fragment", fragment);
}
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Esto tiene que ver con como Android maneja el [ciclo de vida de las Activities](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle), básicamente cuando giras la pantalla Android "destruye" la activity y después la vuelve a crear, esto elimina cualquier estado de la UI. Se me ocurren dos maneras de solucionarlo, la primera es la más simple y la segunda es un poco complicada:

**Solución 1:** Puedes restringir la orientación de la pantalla de esa activity, agregando *android:screenOrientation="portrait"* en el **AndroidManifest.xml**, esa activity solo se verá en vertical y asi evitas perder el estado del checkbox:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"> <!-- Solo en Vertical -->
            .....
</activity>
```

**Solución 2:** 
Puedes solucionarlo utilizando, en el activity donde se ejecuta ese código, el método [onSaveInstanceState()](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#save-simple,-lightweight-ui-state-using-onsaveinstancestate) con esto puedes guardar el estado del checkbox en un [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle):

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // Guardar el estado del checkbox
   savedInstanceState.putInt(ESTADO_CHECKBOX, estadoCheckBox);

   // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
   super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Y para recuperarlo utilizas en el mismo activity el metodo [onRestoreInstanceState()](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#restore-activity-ui-state-using-saved-instance-state):

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Recuperar el estado de los checkboxs
    estadoCheckBox = savedInstanceState.getInt(ESTADO_CHECKBOX);
}
```

Aunque también en la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#restore-activity-ui-state-using-saved-instance-state) se menciona que se puede recuperar el Bundle en el método onCreate(), pero hay que verificar que el bundle *savedIntanceState* no sea *null*.

Comment: Me vale a medias. Ya que mi checkbox se encuentra en un row para un RecyclerView y en el único sitio donde llamo a este checkbox es en Adapter, en el cual no puedo llamar al método onSaveInstanceState().